Help Solving $\int\text{erf}(x)\cos(\alpha x)dx$
I'm trying to solve: $$\int\text{erf}(x)\cos(\alpha x)dx$$ where $\text{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$
I am solving this as part of my attempt to find the Fourier series for $\text{erf}(x)$ for some arbitrary period $p$. I've tried integration by parts but I'm left with $I=I$ and get stuck. My next idea is using Euler's identity to yield $\cos$ in terms of exponentials.

Are you trying to solve tha antiderivative or an integral for some periodic interval?

Moreover, WolframAlpha actually provides an answer but it has no proof.

Writing $\cos(x)$ as an exponential we get
$$I= \frac{1}{2} \, \int \left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} + \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}ax}\right) \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\left[= \int \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x\right]$$
For $\int \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x$ , after IBP :
$$= -\frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{a} - \int -\frac{2\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax - x^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi} \, a} \, \mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{a} -\left[  -\frac{2\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{\pi} \, a} \, \int \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax - x^{2}} \, \mathrm{d}x\right]$$
Under $u = \frac{2x - \mathrm{i}a}{2}$ we get that :
$$\int \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x= \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^{2}}{4}} \operatorname{erf}\left(u\right)}{a} - \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{a}= \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^{2}}{4}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{2x - \mathrm{i}a}{2}\right)}{a} - \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{a}$$
For $\int \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x$ after IBP , substituting $u = \frac{2x + \mathrm{i}a}{2}$ , completing the square and using our previous results (those two integrals are solved identically appart from the u-sub) we get:
$$\int \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x= \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{a} - \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^{2}}{4}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{2x + \mathrm{i}a}{2}\right)}{a}$$
Finally we have:
$$\int \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \cos\left(ax\right) \, \mathrm{d}x= -\frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^{2}}{4}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{2x + \mathrm{i}a}{2}\right)}{2a} + \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^{2}}{4}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{2x - \mathrm{i}a}{2}\right)}{2a} - \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{2a} + \frac{\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}ax} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)}{2a} + C\\= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a^{2}}{4}} \left(\mathrm{i} \operatorname{erf}\left(x - \frac{\mathrm{i}a}{2}\right) - \mathrm{i} \operatorname{erf}\left(x + \frac{\mathrm{i}a}{2}\right)\right)}{2a} + \frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right) \sin\left(ax\right)}{a} + C$$
Which agrees with this .
